# How to create a column based on the value of an element of an array indicated by the other column?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, slice

I have one large data frame and I want to create a column based on the position of an array that is indicated by the other column. In the example below, I want to create a column that assigns the value based on the param array, where the position is indicated by the column "type".

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'type': [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> param = [0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75]
>>> df
   type
0   2
1   3
2   0
3   1
4   4
```

The desired outcome will be

```
>> df
   type  outcome
0   2     0.10
1   3     0.25
2   0     0.30
3   1     0.40
4   4     0.75
```

I couldn't think of a good way to do it without converting the frame into arrays and getting the result through loops. I have tried to create dummy variables for the types and conduct matrix multiplication but since there  are 100+ types in my data, it will increase the computation time drastically. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['outcome'] = [param[i-1] for i in df.type.values]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any for loop you could do:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(param)
df = df.set_index('type').join(df2, how='right').sort_values([0])
```